# How to convert/migrate existing google cloud platform infrastructure to terraform or other IaC

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, infrastructure-as-code

Currently we have our kubernetes cluster master set to zonal, and require it to be regional. My idea is to convert the existing cluster and all workloads/nodes/resources to some infrastructure-as-code - preferably terraform (but could be as simple as a set of `gcloud` commands).

I know with GCP I can generate raw command lines for commands I'm about to run, but I don't know how (or if I even can) to convert existing infrastructure to the same.

Based on my research, it looks like it isn't exactly possible to do what I'm trying to do [in a straight-forward fashion]. So I'm looking for any advice, even if it's just to read some other documentation (for a tool I'm not familiar with maybe).

TL;DR: I'm looking to take my existing Google Cloud Platform Kubernetes cluster and rebuild it in order to change the location type from zonal to master - I don't actually care how this is done. What is a currently accepted best-practice way of doing this? If there isn't one, what is a quick and dirty way of doing this?

If you require me to specify further, I will - I have intentionally left out linking to specific research I've done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a Kubernetes cluster with terraform is very straightforward because ultimately making a Kubernetes cluster in GKE is straightforward, you'd just use the `google_container_cluster` and `google_container_node_pool` resources, like so:

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
  name               = "${var.name}"
  region             = "${var.region}"
  project            = "${var.project_id}"
  min_master_version = "${var.version}"

  addons_config {
    kubernetes_dashboard {
      disabled = true
    }
  }

  maintenance_policy {
    daily_maintenance_window {
      start_time = "03:00"
    }
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = ["node_pool"]
  }

  node_pool {
    name = "default-pool"
  }
}

resource "google_container_node_pool" "default" {
  name    = "default"
  project = "${var.project_id}"
  region  = "${var.region}"
  cluster = "${google_container_cluster.primary.name}"

  autoscaling {
    min_node_count = "${var.node_pool_min_size}"
    max_node_count = "${var.node_pool_max_size}"
  }

  management {
    auto_repair  = "${var.node_auto_repair}"
    auto_upgrade = "${var.node_auto_upgrade}"
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = ["initial_node_count"]
  }

  node_config {
    machine_type = "${var.node_machine_type}"

    oauth_scopes = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
    ]
  }

  depends_on = ["google_container_cluster.primary"]
}
```

For a more fully featured experience, there are terraform modules available like [this one](https://github.com/google-terraform-modules/terraform-google-kubernetes-engine)

Converting an existing cluster is considerably more fraught. If you want to use `terraform import`

```
terraform import google_container_cluster.mycluster us-east1-a/my-cluster
```

However, in your comment , you mentioned wanting to convert a zonal cluster to a regional cluster. Unfortunately, [that's not possible](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/regional-clusters) at this time

> You decide whether your cluster is zonal or regional when you create
>   it. You cannot convert an existing zonal cluster to regional, or vice
>   versa.

Your best bet, in my opinion, is to:

- Create a regional cluster with terraform, giving the cluster a new name
- Backup your existing zonal cluster, either using an etcd backup, or a more sophisticated backup using [heptio-ark](https://github.com/heptio/ark)
- Restore that backup to your regional cluster

Comment: I'm not asking specifically about how to create one. I'm asking about how to convert an existing infrastructure to code. It's a rather large infrastructure and non-trivial. Yes, I could go through all of it and convert it by hand to something like this, but I'd rather not. Either way, thanks for pointing me towards the gke-cluster module, I hadn't seen that yet.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I've updated the answer to include more information about migrating clusters.

Comment: It's funny you mentioned the terraform import - I literally had just found that right as you were writing this I suspect. I'm rebuilding now to test it out. I have many of the deployments and other things backed up and in repos, so I'm not sure it will have to be too terribly difficult - I'm mainly concerned with the google aspect of the backup. Either way, I can accept this answer. Thank you for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to achieve exactly that: Take existing cloud infrastructure and bring it to infrastructure as code (IaC), i.e. put it in `*.tf` files

There were basically 2 options that I found and took into consideration:

1. `terraform import` ([Documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/import/index.html))

   Because of the following limitation `terraform import` did not achieve exactly what I was looking for, because it requires to manually create the resources.

   > The current implementation of Terraform import can only import resources into the state. It does not generate configuration. A future version of Terraform will also generate configuration.
   >
   > Because of this, prior to running terraform import it is necessary to write manually a resource configuration block for the resource, to which the imported object will be mapped.
2. Terraformer ([GitHub Repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer))

   > A CLI tool that generates tf/json and tfstate files based on existing infrastructure (reverse Terraform).

   This tools is provider-agnostic and follows the flow as terraform, i.e. `plan` and `import`. It was able to import specific resources entire workspaces and convet it into `*.tf` files.